# How to expect and receive 404 as normal response in swagger-api/swagger-js, not an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger

Is it possible to configure the Swagger-JS client to not treat a 404 as an error, even expect it?

[In the docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js#http-client) it alludes to this with "Not found" as an example of the normal responses:

```
Swagger.http(request)
  .then((res) => {
    res.statusCode // status code
    res.statusText // status text, ie: "Not Found"
    res.body       // JSON object or undefined
    res.obj        // same as above, legacy
    res.text       // textual body, or Blob
    res.headers    // header hash
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    err            // instanceof Error
    err.response   // response or null
  })
```

However I have found 404's always come in as a caught Error.

In my application I am calling my REST API to get the next item from a queue and 404 is a natural end to the process, not semantically an error in this case.

It's just a nicety, mostly it's annoying that my IDE breaks on the underlying throw in the minified client code at `n.then.a.responseError()`, when I have JS Exception breakpoints turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answering an alternative solution I just thought of, I suppose I could change the API to return a success-class response instead when at the end of the list:

```
204 No Content
The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content
```

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

I'm not sure how common or proper this is in RESTful APIs - I've never used it before.